# How to load 10 post in RecyclerView on Android

Tags: php, android

I want develop android application for one Website. i use `RecyclerView` for show website posts. i want show 10 posts in first entry to app and when scroll this posts show other posts (such as Endless). 
On the website there is only one page and show all posts in one page. **this website json :**

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 18,
    "count_total": 18,
    "pages": 1,
    "posts": [{
        "id": 98,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "%d8%ab%d9%82%d9%81%d8%ba%d8%b9%d9%87",
        "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/?p=98",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "\u062b\u0642\u0641\u063a\u0639\u0647",
        "title_plain": "\u062b\u0642\u0641\u063a\u0639\u0647",
        "content": "<p>\u062a\u0639\u0627\u063a\u0644\u0630\u0631\u0628<\/p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>\u062a\u0639\u0627\u063a\u0644\u0630\u0631\u0628<\/p>\n",
        "date": "2016-04-23 12:15:56",
        "modified": "2016-04-23 12:15:56",
        "categories": [{
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "%d8%af%d8%b3%d8%aa%d9%87%e2%80%8c%d8%a8%d9%86%d8%af%db%8c-%d9%86%d8%b4%d8%af%d9%87",
            "title": "\u062f\u0633\u062a\u0647\u200c\u0628\u0646\u062f\u06cc \u0646\u0634\u062f\u0647",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 0,
            "post_count": 14
        }],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "tellfa",
            "name": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f",
            "url": "http:\/\/codesaz.com",
            "description": "\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0632\u0646\u062f\u06af\u06cc \u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u062a",
            "avatar": "76"
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "thumbnail": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/flat_art_city_in_space_by_suussa-d8ie1d2-150x150.png",
        "custom_fields": {},
        "thumbnail_size": "thumbnail",
        "thumbnail_images": {
            "full": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/flat_art_city_in_space_by_suussa-d8ie1d2.png",
                "width": 1024,
                "height": 576
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/flat_art_city_in_space_by_suussa-d8ie1d2-150x150.png",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "medium": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/flat_art_city_in_space_by_suussa-d8ie1d2-300x169.png",
                "width": 300,
                "height": 169
            },
            "martial-frontpage-blog": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/flat_art_city_in_space_by_suussa-d8ie1d2-771x376.png",
                "width": 771,
                "height": 376
            },
            "martial-blog-profile": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/flat_art_city_in_space_by_suussa-d8ie1d2-371x267.png",
                "width": 371,
                "height": 267
            },
            "martial-blog-profile-thumb": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/flat_art_city_in_space_by_suussa-d8ie1d2-74x67.png",
                "width": 74,
                "height": 67
            }
        }
}
```

I write this codes, but i don't know how to set endless scroll for `RecyclerView` in every 10 posts!
**MainActivity codes:**

```
public class Main_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private ImageView menu_image;
    private RecyclerView main_recyclerView;
    private MainAdapter2 mAdaper;
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<MainDataModel>();
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModelsArray;
    private Context context;
    protected Handler handler;
    private RelativeLayout loadLayout;
    static int id = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
        handler = new Handler();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_empty_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        }
        LoadData();
        // Menu
        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_root);
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);
        menu_image = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo);
        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), menu_image)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();
        // RecyclerView and setData
        main_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
        main_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        main_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mAdaper = new MainAdapter2(this, main_recyclerView, dataModels);
        main_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(List<MainDataModel> mainInfoModels) {
        mAdaper.add(mainInfoModels);

        if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

**AsyncTask code:**

```
public class MainDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;

    public void getMainDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerIP.getIP());
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerIP.getIP())
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(
                                    postObject.getInt("id"),
                                    postObject.getString("title"),
                                    postObject.getString("content"),
                                    postObject.getString("thumbnail")));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter codes:**

```
public class MainAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<MainDataModel> mDateSet;
    private Context mContext;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public MainAdapter2(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, List<MainDataModel> dataSet) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDateSet = dataSet;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();
            recyclerView
                    .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!loading
                                    && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                                // End has been reached
                                // Do something
                                if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                                }
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mDateSet.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.post_card_layout, parent, false);

            vh = new DataViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_title.setText(mDateSet.get(position).getTitle());
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(mDateSet.get(position).getThumbnail())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.post_image)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image);
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getContent()));

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDateSet.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mDateSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mDateSet.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void add(List<MainDataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void update(List<MainDataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.clear();
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView main_post_title, main_post_content;
        private ImageView main_post_image;

        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            main_post_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_title);
            main_post_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_picture_image);
            main_post_content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_text);
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i develop this feature (load 10 post, endless) in my application? tnx all <3

Comment: Can you show the url you are hitting to get the Json

Comment: @RakshitNawani, json link : http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts

Comment: use this link it will give you 10 output http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&count=10

Comment: Use this http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&count=10&page=1 it is useful.

Comment: @RakshitNawani, please see below post. thanks

Comment: @NigamPatro,  
thanks you man, but i am amateur:( can you send to me code with my codes? please

Comment: @fghj : Check the updated answer it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below link it will give you 10 posts as you need

> tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&count=10

and you can add **addOnScrollListener** to add the data list according to your need

***Update***

//Declaration

```
int offSet = 0;
 int limit = 30;


     //Scrolling and adding more data to the recyclerView
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
                int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                int firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                int visibleThreshold = 7; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
                if ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {

                        offSet += limit;
                       //Hit your service 

                }
            }
        });
```

//And when you hit service append the limit in your link so that you can get the data accordingly

Comment: thanks you man, but i am amateur and i really need this help :( can you send me code for this method?`addOnScrollListener` please help me my friend. i need this. thanks

Comment: thanks you my dear friend. but I'm a bit confused :( . can you send me true code with my above codes? please please please :(

Comment: Sorry this is a code from my live project I can add this in your code if you post your full code to get data from that link

Comment: ok man, thank you for help. but just final question. how to write true code in this line : `//Hit your service` . how to go to next page for show other 10 post?

Comment: I suppose you are hitting this link and getting the response from server as you have displayed is your post. so you have to use the response json and show it in your listView/recyclerview. If this help the please accept and up vote my answer. Thank You